# Excel regression output - funky p-value

Tags: microsoft-excel, regression

Anybody know what it means when the p-value for X in an Excel regression output isn't something like ".0263," but instead is "3.9081E-86"?

By the way, this is for one independent and one dependent variable - 268 observations of each - which are "high school class rank" and "SAT score."  The R-squared value is .767

Comment: If my answer was helpful, feel free to accept it by hitting the checkmark next to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The E indicates scientific notation.  3.9081E-86 is 3.9081 x 10^(-86).

Comment: Phoebus, indeed you illuminate the shadows of my poor humanities education.  Duh.  You're the greatest--I tell everybody.

rtw0501

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, a value like the one you have found simply tells that you have used a very large number of observations. Do not put too much importance on it.